# Receiving data from sensor via serial port

Tags: python

0x4D – 0x10 – 0x00 – 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF 0x0FFF - 0x0A //ROW 0 INFORMATION

I'm supposed to receive data as mentioned above.Actually, I want to extract the 2bytes informations one by one. I'm using python in coding.

```
import serial
import array


ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',baudrate=9600)
byte=[]
while 1 :
    c=ser.readline().encode('hex')
        print c
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why did it not work?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, actually i'm new with such topic, i think I have some trouble with the change of the byte seize in the sequence. when I print the data in the terminal I get smth like this " M,/x00,/n, /x0f,/xff....

Comment: But you don't tell us your context. Do you already have a Python code, which you are trying to improve or to make work? Or do you not have anything yet beccause you don't know where to start? If you already have some code, you should post it so we can help you complete it.

Comment: I don't know where to start I have the protocol of the senser i just use python to print the data received from the serial port. the terminal is not showing the hex data I tried to convert it but i'm not getting good results

Comment: I need to see your Python code.

Comment: import serial
import array

    
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',baudrate=9600)
byte=[]
while 1 :
 c=ser.readline().encode('hex')
        print c

Answer (score 0):

> ""Question"":  , I want to extract the 2bytes informations one by one

```
while True:
    bytes = []
    b = ser.readline()
    for i in range(3, len(b)-1, 2): 
        bytes.append( int (b[i:i+2], 16 ) )
```